# How do I insert a multiple list of records into an object which is from the result of a SOQL query in trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I get multiple records from the records list and now I want to insert as new records in an object. Should I create a map or should I do that?

records output is

```
checklistTemplate__c:{Name= Test, Id = xxxxx}, checklistTemplate__c:{Name= Test2, Id = xxxxx2}


trigger CopyChecklistIntoLegitimation on Legitimation__c(after insert){

  //Get the related account's legalstructure of the legitimation
  Set<String> legalStructures = new Set<String>();
  for (Account record : [[Select LegalStructure__c from Account Where Id in 
                                (Select Account__c from Legitimation__c Where Id 
  in :Trigger.New)])
  {
    legalStructures.add(record.LegalStructure__c);
  }

 //Get the checklist templates related with the legal structure from the account related to the legitimization
 List<CustomObject__c> records = [
    Select name from ChecklistTemplate__c Where Entity__c = 'legitimation' And LegalStructure__c IN: legalStructures];

}
```

I am trying to achieve something like this

```
List<Checklist__c> newCheckLists = new List<CheckList__c>();
for(records:r){
newCheckLists.add(new CheckList__c(Name = r.Name, Status = "open", 
                                    LegitimationId__c = Trigger.New));
insert newCheckLists ;
```

//this inserts new Checklist records

Comment: Any answer please?

Comment: Can you post your code using Map, as based on LegalStructure__c you need to insert CustomObject__c records.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a list of records from the query you can list of `Checklist__c` for each `CustomObject__c` as below, no need to create a map.

```
List<ChecklistTemplate__c> records = [SELECT Id,Name FROM ChecklistTemplate__c WHERE Entity__c = 'legitimation' AND LegalStructure__c IN: legalStructures];
List<Checklist__c> newCheckLists = new List<CheckList__c>();

for(CustomObject__c customObj: records){
    Checklist__c checkListObj = new Checklist__c(
        Name = customObj.Name,
        Status = 'open',
        LegitimationId__c = customObj.id;
    );
    newCheckLists.add(newCheckLists);
}

insert newCheckLists;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but here LegitimationId__c cannot be obj.id that it does not come from the records list , but it should come from the legitimation Id which is Trigger.New.

Comment: Hi rahul,  Can I write like this, this worked but not sure..                                                             List<ChecklistTemplate__c> records = [SELECT Id,Name FROM ChecklistTemplate__c WHERE Entity__c = 'legitimation' AND LegalStructure__c IN: legalStructures];                                                                                                   for(legitimation__c l : Trigger.New) {

Comment: @user3920709 is there any relation between? Legitimation__c and ChecklistTemplate__c ?

is LegalStructure__c is unique for all Legitimation__c records?